# Something like thread.join in JMeter?

Tags: performance, jmeter

I have a jmeter test with about 50 users.  the beginning of the test performs a login and some set up stuff.  I don't want this all to happen at the same time as there would be way too much contention for a part of the test I am not interested in. So I have a ramp up period of 10 seconds.  There is then one specific HTTP request where I want the 50 users sending over 1 second interval i.e. a HTTP request every 20 ms.  This is to ensure the 50 users are excuting this part concurrently.  Ideally, something like a thread.join() after the login  / ramp up would help out here, followed by another guassian timer.

Is there something similar to thread.join() in jmeter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To mimic thread.join you can use a [Synchronising Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer), this will block n threads until they reach a point and then execute them all at the same time.

If you want this request load of 1 every 20ms to continue (rather than a single burst) then you can use a [Constant Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) to define the actual rate of requests you want JMeter to run. You can configure each thread to run at a rate of 60 requests per minute and this will give you one hit every 20ms (based on 50 threads with response times always less than 1 second). You can also tell JMeter to just make sure your load is 1/20ms no matter how many threads you use and it will dynamically adjust. This option is perhaps more useful in the context of load testing.

Note. When using a CTT controller, you would probably want to put the login request either in a [Once Only COntroller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) or in a [setup thread grou](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group)p.